# Maps is not displaying in admin site using geopositions

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Django: **2.0.7**

django-geopositions: **0.3.0**

I have configured everything in **SETTINGs** but map does not show at admin site, only lat and long fields are shown.

My model is very simple as:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = GeopositionField()
```

Any idea?

Comment: There are no any mesaages/errors in developer tools.

Comment: [The repository](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition) has not been updated since 2016, so you can't expect it to work in Django 2.0. You could try one of the [pull requests](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition/pulls) which add support for Django 2.0, or perhaps look for a different library which is still being maintained.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair.. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this link:
[pull request](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition/pull/103/files)

And edit your geoposition app as given.